# Best practise to name R functions for CRAN packages?

Tags: r, package, cran

I want to publish an R package via CRAN. In this package, I have functions that

1. simulate data,
2. plot model results,
3. and predict values.

I am struggling to find reasonable function names. I want to use the simple names *simulate*, *plot* and *predict*. However, these names already exist in base R or the stats package and could lead to confusion.

I could

1. ignore this issue,
2. use S3 classes,
3. name the functions *"packagename"_plot*.

What is best practice?

Comment: This is a very opinionated question and is outside the scope of stackoverflow. I would ask the R-devel mailing list for the opinions of active package developers. However, beware as many opinions exist. In your specific case, I would suggest using S3 classes. S3 classes has been implemented for good reasons, and makes code more generalizable. They are very well known and used throughout many (if not most) R packages. So `predict.[class]` for `predict_values` and `plot.[class]` for `plot_model_results` for example.

Comment: Do not ask on R-devel. If you must, ask R-Package-devel.

Comment: thanks @roland I forgot the qualifier.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerous packages that are focused on implementing a particular class have print, format, as.character, summary and other S3 methods corresponding to base generics.  If ggplot2 graphics is supported an autoplot method may be provided and if lattice graphics is supported an xyplot method may be provided.

If the package involves models then such packages will typically have some or all of the methods of `lm`:

```
> methods(class = "lm")
 [1] add1           alias          anova          case.names     coerce        
 [6] confint        cooks.distance deviance       dfbeta         dfbetas       
[11] drop1          dummy.coef     effects        extractAIC     family        
[16] formula        hatvalues      influence      initialize     kappa         
[21] labels         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix   nobs          
[26] plot           predict        print          proj           qr            
[31] residuals      rstandard      rstudent       show           simulate      
[36] slotsFromS3    summary        variable.names vcov          
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

This makes it easy for users to use the package/class since they can use familiar method names leveraging their knowledge of R rather than having to learn new names.

If the package is focused on a particular class then the class name may be made the name of the package as well for simplicity.

There is a tidyverse best practices section in this [document](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html).

Also there is a [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-design.pdf) describing the design principles used in the zoo package mostly consistent with the principles stated in this answer.  Probably some of this needs revision based on experience, for example the use of a zoo bug list would be helpful (the zoo package predated the widespread use of github and github issues in R), but other principles seem well founded.

Agree or not with these documents, putting the design principles for your package in writing can be useful.